# Salvar uma imagem em um banco de dados MySQL usando Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, opencv

Eu não sei como salvar a imagem no banco de dados.

```
 foto =cv2.imread('imagem.jpg')
 hora = str(hora.day) + '/' + str(hora.month) + '/' + str(hora.year) + '-' + str(hora.hour) + ':' + str(hora.minute) + ':' + str(hora.second)
 cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM acesso_usuarios.william')
 cursor.execute('INSERT INTO william (entrada, foto) VALUES (?, ?), (hora, foto))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim, caso não funcione me avise que edito a resposta! Aqui funcionou.

```
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO william (entrada, foto) VALUES (%s, %s)", (hora, foto))
```

Caso tenha dúvidas [clique aqui](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/python-mysql-insert/) e leia um tutorial bem interessante.

Comment: Funcionou, mas como eu faço para salva-la em jpeg